# Subtracting minimum values of a certain pandas dataframe column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I have a huge `pandas` DataFrame `df`, sorted by `id` and then `year`:

```
id        gender        year
3         male          1983
3         male          1983
3         male          1985
3         male          1990
6         female        1991
6         female        1992
7         male          1980
...
592873    female        1989
592873    female        1996
593001    male          2001
593428    female        2007
593428    female        2009
```

My goal is to create another column `ca` which is computed by:

- `year` - minimum `year` of that `id`

Hence, the first six rows of `df` should return:

```
id        gender        year        ca
3         male          1983        0
3         male          1983        0
3         male          1985        2
3         male          1990        7
6         female        1991        0
6         female        1992        1
```

(In other words, I'm searching for a Pythonic answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979757/subtract-minimum-of-the-column-based-on-other-column).)

---

One solution I could think of is to make a list and use a `for` loop:

```
ca_list = []

for i in range(len(df)):
  if df['id'][i] != df['id'][i-1]:
    num = df['year'][i]
    ca_list.append(0)
  else:
    ca_list.append(df['year'][i] - num)

df['ca'] = ca_list
```

But I believe there is a more optimal way to devise this. Any insights are much appreciated.

Comment: Since you're grouping by 'id' column, both pandas and R generally use [Split-Apply-Combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) approaches; please skim that quickstart.

Comment: Since your dataframe is already sorted by 'id' then 'year', the min(year) will occur on the first line for that 'id' value. So you could determine it at read time, by wrapping and chunking the reader code. And if you have an issue with memory, just chunk the reader code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["ca"] = df.groupby("id")["year"].transform(lambda x: x - x.min())
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id  gender  year  ca
0   3    male  1983   0
1   3    male  1983   0
2   3    male  1985   2
3   3    male  1990   7
4   6  female  1991   0
5   6  female  1992   1
```

Comment: Thank you, that definitely works; out of curiosity, as it takes up to about a minute due to the sample size, is there another way to reduce the runtime?

Comment: @raven What is the sample size? Try `df["ca"] = df["year"] - df.groupby("id")["year"].transform("min")`

Comment: @raven: how large is your dataframe? (rows x columns)? If you want performance comparison of alternatives on large dataframes, please post code that generates a big seeded-random dataframe, using `np.random.seed()`.

Comment: ...and if it's because you're reading in a huge dataframe which blows out memory, you could **chunk the read, and compute `min(year)` as you read it in** (it'll be the first line for that 'id' value, since your dataframe is sorted). So you wouldn't need to spend any extra memory for this computation.